# Why adding a new DateTime filter in a Where clausule involves bad performance?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have the next query, that returns about 100 rows:

```
SELECT fecha,p_01,p_02,p_03,p_04,p_05,p_06
FROM values_periods_view
WHERE 
    indicator_number='460' 
    AND indicador_date>='20210101' 
    AND indicator_date<='20211231'
```

The query takes up to 5 minutes. If I modify the filters in the Where clausule like this: (removing the last datetime filter)

```
SELECT fecha,p_01,p_02,p_03,p_04,p_05,p_06
FROM values_periods_view
WHERE 
    indicator_number='460' 
    AND indicador_date>='20210101'
```

the query time it's reduce at 10 seconds.

Somebody can tell me how to improve the response times and why is happening this bad performance when i use DateTimes in Where clausule?

Before answer, i'm going to let you some information about DB state:

- All columns that are used for search have index and the index as been rebuild before to throw the query
- Statistics are updated
- *values_periods_view* it's a simple view that not have any conversion over the *indicador_date* column, this column it's just a DateTime Nullable.
- Database have many inserts and modifications daily (i thought that updating the statistics could be resolve the problem, but after update statistics the results are very similar)
- Execution Plan: https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan/?id=BJGmt3Ord

**Note** The DB is: Microsoft SQL Server 2012 - 11.0.2100.60 (X64)

Comment: Why are you using indicator_number as a string? Strings are not numbers.

Comment: Any useful comment will have to be based on what the query in the (preumably a view) is doing, the base table schemas and their indexes. Also the actual execution plan using [PasteThePlan](https://www.brentozar.com/pastetheplan)

Comment: @Stu indicator_number must be a string due to a bussiness requirement. For example an indicador_number could be a 123b_32

Comment: @GonzaloMartinez please provide execution plan by using the link stu provided

Comment: Can you show us the `values_periods_view` definition?

Comment: Please [edit] and add full `CREATE TABLE` statements **including indexes**, `CREATE VIEW` statement (which it looks like you have also), and share query plans using the link above

Comment: So this is most likely due to KEYLOOKUP operator in the execution plan. Adding a where clause predicate to a query and then experiences performance degradation is often due ot the extra work the compiler has to do to check the table for those values when not part of the index. Essentially what happens is it has to use whatever index might exist for it and in the worst case scenario it can clustered scan or table scan (EEEWWWW) to try and accommodate the request.,

Comment: I'm surprised someone flagged my comment about the version of SQL Server the OP used to be removed; It's *really* important that the OP patches their software. To repeat myself Build 11.0.2100.60 is SQL Server 2012 **RTM**; that means it's the version that was released 9 years ago, no updates, no patches, no bug fixes, no security flaws addressed; nada. There are 9 years of updates the OP ***really needs*** to apply here. There are multiple security flaws that have been address over the hears on SQL Server 2012, and the OP is likely vulnerable to many of them.